# Learning ROS2 without ROS1 background

Tags: ros, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to learn ROS2 without knowing ROS1? Is it worth it to try?

Many ROS2 resources I see describe themselves with respect to the ROS1 resource that implemented that functionality.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327827/learning-ros2-without-ros1-background/) by [johnconn](https://answers.ros.org/users/43713/johnconn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 553 on 2019-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's possible, but with the current state of ROS 2 material / documentation I would probably suggest to get at least *some* experience with ROS 1.

You'll probably have a much easier time matching ROS 1 domain concepts with their analogues in ROS 2.

You will have to "unlearn" some things though (nodelets fi don't exist in ROS 2) but most of the times at least the concept is similar which allows you to employ conceptual reuse (the idea of nodelets can be mapped to ROS 2 nodes running in the same component and using zero-copy exchange of messages). That helps me personally tremendously.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-08**:
Related recent Q&A: #q327456.

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2019-07-08**:
I agree with gvdhoorn, ROS has a steep learning curve and ROS1 is pretty well documented with a low of materials, examples and implementation. In some cases ROS1 and ROS2 are used alongside so its good to be familiar with both of them.